# how to stop this infinite loop

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, infinite

I'm trying to make a number guessing game where if the user matches the lucky number they win cash, the game goes on until they run out of cash. They pay a stake for each round they play. Each round there is a new random number that is generated.

I only want to use one input.
When I put the input in the loop, the loop stops looping infinitely, when I take it outside the loop, it starts looping infinitely. How do I stop this? What do I need to add to the while loop?
I tried break but I want to game to continue until the money is gone.

I just want to use one input, but when I take the input out the loop (lucky_guess) it goes on forever. I just want the user to guess once.

```
funds = 1000
stake = 1
luckyNumber = 25 #test number #random number from 1 - 30

while funds != 0:
    funds = funds - 1
    print("Your Funds", funds)
    luckyGuess = int(input("enter a number")) #this is the problem if i take this out, the loop wont stop

    if luckyNumber == luckyGuess:
        print("Number is",luckyNumber, " You Win, +35 added to your funds")
        funds = funds + 35
    else:
        print("Fail, Try Again")
```

Comment: Fix the indentation in your code block and then we can help you. As it is, it's impossible to determine what is wrong and what is bad pasting.

Comment: Proper indentation will solve your problem. **Python Uses Indention Instead of Curly Brackets.**

Comment: I can't reproduce any infinite loop. Either you've fixed the issue while fixing your indentation, or there's something else going on (such a `funds` starting negative, perhaps).

Comment: The problem might be that the "cost" or "stake" for each round is too less compared to initial funds, and not that of an infinite loop. try testing with a smaller starting fund maybe? 
The code seems fine as per your description.

Comment: i want to use one input, the code is showing the input within the loop the problem with this it loops the input again, i dont want this. i just want one input and be able to use that same input for all loops

Comment: @laflare: that doesn't really make much sense in terms of gameplay. If you use the same input value, you'll either always be wrong or always be right. That takes away the whole point of the loop, I'd think.

Comment: they will be a new number each round,
but the number will stay the same
the loop is there to run the game until the user runs out of money

Comment: @laflare I think, as pointed out by Blckknght, your luckyNumber  condition never meets luckyGuess. Since there is no change in luckyGuess, your loop runts infite. Pleaes change logic in a way, luckyGuess is different in each run. Thats the only possible way to meet your requirement of : having only 1 input.

Comment: @laflare, How about trying a condition to ask the user if he wants to continue playing, and then take the input? 
You can not take the input condition out of the loop, for you need to let the user guess a number for each round of the game.

Comment: thank you @Aramis7d this worked :+)

Comment: perfect. I added the code as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the formatting should be like this:

```
funds = 1000
stake = 1
luckyNumber = 25 #test number #random number from 1 - 30

while funds != 0:
   funds = funds - 1
   print("Your Funds", funds)
   luckyGuess = int(input("enter a number"))

   if luckyNumber == luckyGuess  :
       print("Number is",luckyNumber, " You Win, +35 added to your funds")
       funds = funds + 35
   else:
       print("Fail, Try Again")
```

Comment: i just want to use one input, but when i take the input out the loop (lucky_guess) it goes on forever. i just want the user to guess once.

Answer (score 0):

Use `break` keyword to exit the loop:

```
funds = 1000
stake = 1
luckyNumber = 25 #test number #random number from 1 - 30

while funds != 0:
    funds = funds - 1
    print("Your Funds", funds)
    luckyGuess = int(input("enter a number")) #this is the problem if i take this out, the loop wont stop

    if luckyNumber == luckyGuess:
        print("Number is",luckyNumber, " You Win, +35 added to your funds")
        funds = funds + 35

        break
    else:
        print("Fail, Try Again")
```

You may find out more about control flow directives in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-break)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps

```
funds = 1000
stake = 1
luckyNumber = 25 #test number #random number from 1 - 30

while funds != 0:
    funds = funds - 1
    print("Your Funds", funds)
    play = input("play more? (y/n)")
    if( ( play == 'y') or (play == 'Y')): #condition to check for continuing gameplay
        luckyGuess = int(input("enter a number"))
    else:
        break
    if luckyNumber == luckyGuess  :
        print("Number is",luckyNumber, " You Win, +35 added to your funds")
        funds = funds + 35
    else:
        print("Fail, Try Again")
```